# Security protocol between web client and Java server

Tags: javascript, java, html, security, srp-protocol

I'm trying to develop a security layer between a web client (HTML) and a server. Due to technical limitations HTTPS can't be enabled.

How can I secure the server so that only requests from trusted sources are processed?

I have looked into [Nimbus SRP](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-srp) but a password would have to be stored in the client side and thus being visible for inspection.

Comment: What kind of technical limitations do you have that prevents HTTPS?

Comment: Surely you investigated more options than only this one example.

Comment: @Kayaman This is imposed by the client. It is related with their architecture.

Comment: @Gimby It's an example. I'm trying to gather as much information as I can.

Comment: I hope you have real experience with security. Otherwise this has a high chance of resulting in tears and security breaches.

Comment: @Kayaman That's what I'm affraid of.